# Not able to combine plots using subplot command

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have following simple pandas dataframe:

```
   A  B  C   D
0  1  8  9  50
1  5  4  1  70
2  7  2  4  90
```

Following code works to plot separate graphs one after other:

```
df.drop("D", axis=1).plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

df['D'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

However, I am not able to combine these into one graph using [suplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) command:

```
plt.subplot(211)
df.drop("D", axis=1).plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(212)
df['D'].plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Following code produces 2 plots but only one graph. There is no error message. Where is the problem?

Comment: when you say combine you mean plotting two charts in the same pair of axis? or two have two subplots in the same figure? it is not clear what you want

Comment: I have provided subplot link in my question above. I want to have plot as shown on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `df.plot`, you can specify which axes you want to plot onto.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
df.drop("D", axis=1).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
df['D'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Shows both plots:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works well. Why is ax needed here since subplot statements work without specifying ax in plots without dataframes.

Comment: @rnso it's due to the implementation in `pandas`, though I don't know any more specifically than that. It's a good habit to use named axes though, as you then are able to modify their parameters.